# Make plugin to element specific

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following js plugin to catch show hide events of elements. But i want to make it specific to One dom element only, i.e #div_loading_page

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.each(['show','hide'], function (i, ev) {
        var el = $.fn[ev];
        $.fn[ev] = function () {
                this.trigger(ev);
                el.apply(this, arguments);

        };
    });
});
```

can anyone please help. thanks

Comment: compare your id inside plugin if it is that one (div_loading_page) let the function run.. else return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.each(['show','hide'], function (i, ev) {
        var el = $.fn[ev];
        $.fn[ev] = function () {

            this.each(function () {
                if ( this.id == 'div_loading_page') {
                    $(this).trigger(ev);
                    return false; // break out of the loop
                }
            });

            el.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but It didn't help much, i had to remove hide event and add it's logic on click of close button.